# Scala way of merging tuples in a list using functional programming techniques

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Say I have:

```
val list: List[(Long, Boolean)] = List((0, false), (0, true), (1, true), (1, true))
```

and in the end I want:

```
List((0, false), (1, true))
```

Where the "Merged" list "Groups By" _1 and then "logically and" the results.

I can do this with iteration but it seems like Scala and functional programming in general should be able to use a set of functions to perform this transformation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val result = list.groupBy(_._1) // group by key
  .mapValues(_.map(_._2))       // remove keys from grouped values
  .mapValues(_.reduce(_ && _))  // reduce grouped values using &&
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`List#groupBy`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#groupBy[K](f:A=>K):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,Repr]) followed by a sequence of map/reduce operations:

```
scala> List((0, false), (0, true), (1, true), (1, true))
res0: List[(Int, Boolean)] =
  List((0,false), (0,true), (1,true), (1,true))

scala> .groupBy(_._1)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[(Int, Boolean)]] =
  Map(1 -> List((1,true), (1,true)), 0 -> List((0,false), (0,true)))

scala> .mapValues(_.map(_._2))
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Boolean]] =
  Map(1 -> List(true, true), 0 -> List(false, true))

scala> .mapValues(_.reduce(_ && _))
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Boolean] =
  Map(1 -> false, 0 -> true)

scala> .toList
res4: List[(Int, Boolean)] =
  List((1,false), (0,true))
```

Comment: Is the `List#groupBy` notation similar to C++ `"<class>::<function>"` notation? New to Scala.